# How can I replicate the label of this bottle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to replicate the label of the water bottle shown here:

[image]

I would like to recreate it in Illustrator. I've tried a few different methods with mixed results, none of which are really a match for the ripple style of the label itself. The closest I've come is using offset path to create the radial pattern and putting a calligraphic stroke on the result, but it's still not quite right. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but it looks to me as if there's a blur effect applied to those lines. You might consider expanding the strokes, then applying a blur.

If you have AI CS5.1, use the variable stroke width tool for finer control, rather than a calligraphic brush.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the smaller MyCause Logo is on the front of the bottle. And the larger blue lines that run the length are actually on the back of the bottle.  What you're seeing is the effect of both back and front blending together in the photo, with the logo being in focus, and the background distorted by the water inside and curvature of the bottle.  Cool effect though.

You might try drawing the bottle front and back separately. Putting each on their respective layers, you can then experiment with blurring, ripple, and distortion filters on the background layer.

Hope this helps.